# Maximum a Posteriori (MAP) Estimator of Exponential Random Variable with Uniform Prior

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, estimation, parameter-estimation

What would be the Maximum a Posteriori (MAP) estimator for $ \lambda $ for IID $ \left\{ {x}_{i} \right\}_{i = 1}^{N} $ where $ {x}_{i} \sim \exp \left( \lambda \right), \; \lambda \sim U \left[ {u}_{0}, {u}_{1} \right] $?

One could assume that $u_0 > 0 $.

The [Exponential Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) is given by:

$$ f(x; \lambda) = \begin{cases}
\lambda {e}^{-\lambda x} & x \ge 0, \\
0 & x < 0.
\end{cases} $$

Comment: Exponentially distributed with "parameter" $\lambda$ sometimes means with _expected value_ $\lambda$, so that the density is $\displaystyle\vphantom{\frac\int\int}\frac 1 \lambda e^{-x/\lambda}$ for $x>0$, and sometimes it means with density $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ for $x>0$, so that the expected value is $1/\lambda$.  Which did you intend here? ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a likelihood function
$$
L(\lambda) = (\lambda e^{-\lambda x_1})\cdots(\lambda e^{-\lambda x_n}) = \lambda^n e^{-\lambda(x_1+\cdots+x_n)}, \tag 1
$$
and
$$
\ell(\lambda)=\log L(\lambda) = n\log\lambda -\lambda(x_1+\cdots+x_n) \tag 2
$$
The density of the uniform distribution on the interval $\lambda\in[u_0,u_1]$ does not depend on $\lambda$.  Therefore the posterior density is proportional to $(1)$ on the interval $[u_0,u_1]$.  The maximum value of the posterior density therefore occurs at the point in the interval $[u_0,u_1]$ where $(1)$ attains its maximum value.  Since $(2)$ is an increasing function of $(1)$, that is the same as the point in the interval $[u_0,u_1]$ where $(2)$ attains its maximum.  We have
$$
\ell'(\lambda) = \frac n \lambda - (x_1+\cdots+x_n)\quad\begin{cases} >0 & \text{if }0<\lambda < \bar x = (x_1+\cdots+x_n)/n, \\[6pt]
=0 & \text{if } \lambda=\bar x, \\[6pt]
<0 & \text{if } \lambda>\bar x. \end{cases}
$$
Therefore the maximum value is attained at
$$
\lambda = \begin{cases} u_0 & \text{if } u_0 > \bar x, \\[6pt]
\bar x & \text{if } u_0\le\bar x\le u_1, \\[6pt]
u_1 & \text{if }u_1<\bar x. \end{cases}
$$
If you like, you can write this as
$$
\lambda = (u_0 \vee \bar x) \wedge u_1 = u_0 \vee (\bar x \wedge u_1)
$$
where $a\vee b$ is whichever of $a,b$ is bigger and $a\wedge b$ is whichever is smaller.

Comment: I think you have a mistake in the cases for $ \lambda $. I will add suggested edit.

Comment: By the way, do you find it any different from my own answer? Anyhow, marked it +1.

Answer (score 5):

Working by the definition of the MAP estimator:

$$ \begin{align}
{\hat{\lambda}}_{MAP} & =  \arg \max_{\mu} f \left( x \mid \lambda \right) f \left( \lambda \right) \\
& = \prod_{i = 1}^{N} \lambda \exp \left( - \lambda {x}_{i} \right) f \left( \lambda \right) \\
& = {\lambda}^{N} \exp \left( - \lambda \sum_{i = 1}^{N} {x}_{i} \right) \mathbb{1}_{ \left\{ {u}_{0} \leq \lambda \leq {u}_{1} \right\} } \\
\end{align}
$$

By applying the logarithm on the Likelihood Function one would get $ {\hat{\lambda}}_{ML} = \frac{1}{\bar{x}} $ where $ \bar{x} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i = 1}^{N} {x}_{i} $.
Since the likelihood is continuous and it is multiplied by a window (The indicator function), its maximum is either inside the range or on its boundaries.
Hence the answer is given by:

$$ {\hat{\lambda}}_{MAP} = \min \left({u}_{1}, \max \left( {u}_{0}, {\hat{\lambda}}_{ML} \right) \right) $$